# String Extraction from Text File

Tags: string, vb.net, text, extract

I have a very weird text file that has some data that I need to extract. I really don't know the best approach and I need guide on what would be the best idea how to do it. The text looks like this:

[Picture of Data to Extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAW42.png)

Basically the file contains that data. and I would need to extract each parameter AA - FF for each "column" of data. There are some spaces in between each number..

1. Is it possible to find the word AA, move to after the "--" characters and copy such number until there are spaces.... and repeat through the line?
   or,
2. Is it easier to try to fit that data into a table that is separated by spaces?

No idea how to start this and hence asking for help.
Regards, 
DH

Comment: I had to add the text as a picture because I couldn't find how to format it to show how I need it to show.

Comment: I am trying to use VB.NET

Comment: Read each line as space separated (split on space), throw away the empties, and you're left with all your data. Put some code together, show us the said code and we'll help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would read each line and separate them on spaces, throwing away empties.
That will leave you with a list of fields. In this sample, I create a *list of list of fields* in the form of a `List(Of List(Of string))`. This creates a list of fields for each line and I think it makes it easy to iterate and store them.

Vb.net sample

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim fieldsOfEachLine As New List(Of List(Of String))

        Dim reader As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader("F:\SlyWorkspace\StackOverflow\SpaceSeparatedText_47337929\sampledata.txt")
        Dim currentLine As String

        Do
            currentLine = reader.ReadLine()
            If currentLine IsNot Nothing Then
                fieldsOfEachLine.Add(currentLine.Split(New Char() {" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList())
            End If
        Loop Until currentLine Is Nothing

        reader.Close()

        'once you have your fields neatly placed in a list, it's up
        'to you to decide what you want to do with them
        'for this sample, I will just spit them back out the screen using a \ to delimit the information I kept
        For Each item As List(Of String) In fieldsOfEachLine
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\", item))
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Here's a quick c# sample.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace CSharp_SpaceSeparatedText_47337929
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<List<string>> fieldsForEachLine = new List<List<string>>();
            string currentLine = string.Empty;
            using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"F:\SlyWorkspace\StackOverflow\SpaceSeparatedText_47337929\sampledata.txt"))
            {
                while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    fieldsForEachLine.Add(currentLine.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList());
                }
            }

            foreach (List<string> item in fieldsForEachLine)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join("/", item));
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

my datafile contains this

```
                           1                      2                     3          
                bu                     AU                    BG
AA               --      929.2244             1074.4697                 1114.7150
BB               --        1.458             1074.4697              1114.7150
CC           --    456.4584    448.4     584.5
DD  -- 1234.458      789.456                             4898.45
```

My output is this

```
1\2\3
bu\AU\BG
AA\--\929.2244\1074.4697\1114.7150
BB\--\1.458\1074.4697\1114.7150
CC\--\456.4584\448.4\584.5
DD\--\1234.458\789.456\4898.45
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me check this code and see how I can adapt it. But this is definitely a great start. I really appreciate it.